# Initializing std::list elements of a std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map of type `<const char *, std::list<void *>>`, and I have a large list of values I am iterating through to see if there is a match on some condition. If there is a match, I want to append a pointer to a certain value to the std::list at the index of the value.

```
const char *handler_name = NULL;
while (handler_name = all_handlers->get(), handler_name)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        //Add pointer element to every event handler it registers
        std::list<void *> scripts = responders[handler_name];
        if (scripts.size() == 0)
        {
            responders[handler_name] = scripts;
        }
        scripts.push_back(static_cast<void *> (L));
        active_states[static_cast<void *> (L)] = 1; //set to active so we only delete it once
    }
    handler_name = NULL;
}
```

These are my variable declarations:

```
private:
    std::unordered_map<const char*, std::list<void *>> responders;
    std::unordered_map<void *, int> active_states;
```

`all_handlers` is a custom list type which I am iterating over correctly, if unconventionally to obtain all of the const char * C strings to use as potential keys, if there is a match on condition.

However, gdb reveals that a std::list is never being initialized for the key of interest, and I think it has something to do with my fear of initializing a std::list for every value of handler_name, and simultaneously needing to check the entry to see if the list already exists before appending a new value.

What is the best way to do proper initialization in this case?

Comment: please post a [MCVE]

Comment: @m.s.: apart from the `condition`, this question looks quite complete to me.  OP clearly has a problem understanding 'initialization', and does not know the difference between references and values.

Comment: It's not complete. What is `all_handlers`? Where do the `const char*` values come from? Is the OP assuming that string literals with the same contents compare equal using `==`? There are several assumptions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char* handler_name = NULL;
while (handler_name = all_handlers->get(), handler_name)
```

This is not an idiomatic way to write a loop. In fact it's **very** weird.

Consider a more conventional approach:

```
const char* handler_name = NULL;
while ((handler_name = all_handlers->get()))
```

(The double parentheses are necessary to prevent some compilers from issuing a warning about a possible confusion between `=` and `==`).

Or using `for` instead:

```
for (const char* handler_name = all_handlers->get(); handler_name; handler_name = all_handlers->get())
```

> my fear of initializing a std::list for every value of handler_name,

I have no idea what this means. The expression `responders[handler_name]` will initialize an empty `std::list` for that value if there isn't one in the map already. But that's what you need to happen.

This is nonsense:

```
    std::list<void *> scripts = responders[handler_name];
    if (scripts.size() == 0)
    {
        responders[handler_name] = scripts;
    }
    scripts.push_back(static_cast<void *> (L));
```

First it evaluates `responders[handler_name]`, which returns the `std::list` corresponding to that key (creating an empty one if it isn't there already).

Then it copies that list into a new object called `scripts`.

Then if `scripts` is not empty it *replaces* the value in the map by copying `scripts` (which **must** be completely pointless, because `scripts` ia a copy of the value in the map, so if `scripts` is not empty then the one in the map is already not empty).

Then finally you modify the *copy* of the list, `scripts`, which is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the loop, so you never add any entries to the list stored in the map.

> and simultaneously needing to check the entry to see if the list already exists before appending a new value.

You don't need to do that. `responses[handler_name]` does that for you. If there's no entry for that key one will be created.

> What is the best way to do proper initialization in this case?

Stop worrying about nothing, and then writing pointless code to try to avoid a non-issue. `responses[handler_name]` performs all the initialization you need. It looks for a list corresponding to that key, and if no list is found then an empty one is properly initialized.

That whole chunk of nonsense can be written as simply:

```
    responses[handler_name].push_back(static_cast<void *> (L));
    active_states[static_cast<void *> (L)] = 1; //set to active so we only delete it once
```

The `static_cast<void*>` probably isn't even necessary, since any pointer will implicitly convert to `void*`. You can keep them if you want to be more explicit about the conversion, but I would simply write:

```
for (auto handler_name = all_handlers->get(); handler_name; handler_name = all_handlers->get())
{
    if (condition)
    {
        //Add Lua state to every event handler it registers
        responses[handler_name].push_back(L);
        active_states[L] = 1; //set to active so we only delete it once
    }
}
```

This is much shorter, much simpler, and doesn't contain muddled code to solve problems that don't exist.

Comment: You're writing contains truth, but personally I would feel slightly insulted by the wording of it.

Comment: @xtofl I wouldn't. Code can objectively be nonsense, or at least pointlessly-obfuscated-sense. If so, that should just be stated as-is. There's nothing offensive or personal here. And there's no point in playing kid-gloves for every possible - and misinterpreted - emotional reaction someone might have. Anyway, let them complain if they want to, and they can discuss it with the author - no point backseat-driving.

Comment: My comments are about the code, not the author of it. Copying an object out of a container then conditionally copying it back in again _is_ nonsensical. It's not just poor style, or a bit inefficient, it is entirely redundant and doesn't contribute to solving the problem. I wanted to stress that, not just say "here's a better way to do it". Good programming requires clear thinking and deliberate action based on proper understanding, especially in C++.

Comment: While I agree that `if (scripts.size() == 0)
        {
            responders[handler_name] = scripts;
        }` doesn't really make sense, it shouldn't break the code. Originally, I didn't have that block, and I was still missing my element in gdb (empty list for the correct key, and I confirmed that the condition WAS executed). Is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: After modifying to responses[handler_name].push_back(L), the value is being pushed. Thanks for the help -- still a bit confused about why exactly my funky code wasn't working though.

Comment: Both answers tell you why. The relevant part of mine is _"Then finally you modify the copy of the list, `scripts`, which is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the loop, so you never add any entries to the list stored in the map."_ You were modifying the copy, not the one in the map, so none of the lists in the map ever got changed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `condition` is not an always-false expression, ...

Your `list`s *are* initialized as soon as an entry is added to the `responders` map.  That's C++: you can't have 'uninitialized' lists.  They're fully constructed, or they don't exist.  (Readup on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization))

This code fragment:

```
    std::list<void *> scripts = responders[handler_name];
    if (scripts.size() == 0)
    {
        responders[handler_name] = scripts;
    }
```

Is a no-op.  The `scripts` variable is *copied* (value semantics!) from the `responders[handler_name]`.  If the latter was empty, you're just copying it back...

Probably you mean to take *a reference to* the list in the entry, and add to that:

```
auto & scripts = responders[handler_name];
scripts.push_back(static_cast<void *> (L));
```

(Note: if every you want to know if a list is empty, use `list.empty()`... much clearer!  [Express intent](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rp-what)!)